# SEG FAULT with boost::make_shared / eigen3 memory.h

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, point-cloud-library, eigen3, linux-mint

I am getting a segmentation fault with the following code below. However, this only happens on my Mint 19 system running gcc 7.3 and boost 1.65, PCL 1.8.1, Eigen3.4.4 On my other system (running Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4,  boost 1.58, 1.8.0, Eigen3.3 beta1-2) this run time error does not occur.

I have traced the error in debug mode. Strangely, the function code is executed until the end and the debugger then jumps back up the function to the line

```
typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloudFiltered =  boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<PointT> >();
```

tracing this call further, the debugger arrives at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h at:

```
inline void handmade_aligned_free(void *ptr)
{
  if (ptr) std::free(*(reinterpret_cast<void**> (ptr) - 1 );
}
```

here the SEG FAULT occurs on the machine with (gcc 7.3, boost 1.65, Eigen3.3.4 and PCL 1.8.1). I have a work-around by which I pass pcl::PointCloud::Ptr &cloudFiltered from the outside to this function and obviously delete the declaration of this variable in the function below. This works. However, this is not really what I want and I have similar situations in other functions where I don't want to do it this way and I assume the same error will occur once I reach this point... 
Also, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here, rather than just applying a hot fix...

```
template <typename PointT>
int
readLAS2PCD(std::string fileToRead,
        typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr &cloud,          
        const float gridLeafSize)
{

// 1) create a file stream object to access the file
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(fileToRead, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
// if the LAS file could not be opend. throw an error (using the PCL_ERROR functionality).
if (!ifs.is_open())
{
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file ");
    return -1;
}

// set up ReaderFactory of the LibLAS library for reading in the data.
std::cout << "Reading in LAS input file: " << fileToRead << std::endl;

liblas::ReaderFactory f;
liblas::Reader reader = f.CreateWithStream(ifs);

liblas::Header const& header = reader.GetHeader();

long int nPts = header.GetPointRecordsCount();
std::cout << "Compressed:  " << (header.Compressed() == true) ? "true\n":"false\n";
std::cout << "\nSignature: " << header.GetFileSignature() << '\n';
std::cout << "Points count: " << nPts << '\n';


// Fill in the PCD cloud data
cloud->width    = nPts;
cloud->height   = 1;
cloud->is_dense = false;
cloud->points.resize (cloud->width * cloud->height);
int i = 0;

  while (reader.ReadNextPoint()){
    liblas::Point const& p = reader.GetPoint();


    cloud->points[i].x = static_cast<float>( p.GetX() );
    cloud->points[i].y = static_cast<float>( p.GetY() );
    cloud->points[i].z = static_cast<float>( p.GetZ() );
    cloud->points[i].intensity = p.GetIntensity();

    if (i % 500000 == 0)
        std::cout << i  << "  x: " << p.GetX() << "  y: " << p.GetY() << "  z: " << p.GetZ() << "\n";


    i++;
}


//here the seg fault happens after the lines below have been executed (on the way out of the function)
typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloudFiltered =  boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<PointT> >();


if (gridLeafSize > 0.029 && gridLeafSize < 1){
  std::cout << "\nApplying Uniform downsampling with leafSize " << gridLeafSize << ". Processing...";

  pcl::UniformSampling<PointT> uniform_sampling;
  uniform_sampling.setInputCloud (cloud);
  uniform_sampling.setRadiusSearch (gridLeafSize); //the 3D grid leaf size
  uniform_sampling.filter(*cloudFiltered);      
  pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloudFiltered, *cloud);  // cloud is given by reference so the downsampled cloud has to be copied in there

}
else  // else copy original cloud in cloud Filtered and save file...
    pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloud,*cloudFiltered);

std::string fileToWrite = fileToRead + ".pcd";
std::cout << "Writing PCD output file: " << fileToWrite << std::endl;
pcl::io::savePCDFile (fileToWrite, *cloudFiltered,true);
std::cerr << "Saved " << cloudFiltered->points.size () << " Points to " << fileToWrite << std::endl;

return (0);
```

}

EDIT:

I have never used valgrind before, so I am not sure if i used it correctly. The summary states or indicates that there might be dangling pointers.

```
==11556== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11556==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11556==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11556==      possibly lost: 1,508,328,093 bytes in 119 blocks
==11556==    still reachable: 713,529,397 bytes in 19,422 blocks
==11556==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11556== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==11556== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==11556== 
==11556== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11556== ERROR SUMMARY: 119 errors from 119 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The error report is pretty long and it appears at various places are potentially some bytes lost. Also in many library functions (of opencv - which i am not even using at this point in the code, Eigen, etc...)

I will try to add some test code later...

Comment: Can you reduce the test code any more (and complete it with the missing headers and other code) and still provoke the problem?  That would help.  And have you run under Valgrind or similar?  That's usually a good start when fighting dangling pointers and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas. To solve your issue with the fault, maybe allocate some new memory for that cloudFiltered cloud:

```
typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloudFiltered =  boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<PointT> >(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointCloud<PointT>>());
```

The one time I used the .filter method with a new cloud, the cloud declaration looked like this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
```

On the other hand, it looks like you can get by without creating a new variable. Just edit the input cloud if you reach that if statement. Try:

```
if (gridLeafSize > 0.029 && gridLeafSize < 1){
std::cout << "\nApplying Uniform downsampling with leafSize " << gridLeafSize << ". Processing...";

pcl::UniformSampling<PointT> uniform_sampling;
uniform_sampling.setInputCloud (cloud);
uniform_sampling.setRadiusSearch (gridLeafSize); //the 3D grid leaf size
uniform_sampling.filter(*cloud);  // EDIT. Output cloud is your filtered input cloud
// pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloudFiltered, *cloud);  // Do not need to store points in a new variable

}
// EDIT: Else, do nothing to your input cloud. No longer need the else!
//else
//    pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloud,*cloudFiltered);
```

Let us know if either of those options work for you!